# Query to select one column data out of n columns given data exists

Tags: sql-server

A table(ex: testdata) has 5 columns with cash limit data for example: CashLimitAnnual, CashLimitQuarter, CashLimitMonth, CashLimitWeekly, CashLimitDaily.

I would like to write a sql query to select only the column which has data else ignore the others as only 1 out of these columns at any time can have data(others have value either as 0000000 or 00000000).
Query I am trying out works out when comparing two columns only:

```
select a.CompanyNumber, b.CoName, a.AutoDirectDebitInd,a.OptCashMinimum as Minimum,
(select case when 
     a.OptCashLimitMonth = '00000000' then  a.OptCashLimitAnnual 
     else a.OptCashLimitMonth end as Test) as Test      
from SQLcheck.dividend.dbo.testdata a, dbo.testcompany b 
where a.CompanyNumber=1234 and a.CompanyNumber = b.CoNumber
```

How do I extrapolate this for comparing 5 columns?

Comment: `OptCashLimitMonth` is a varchar column? So all those 5 columns above can be null, empty, `0000000` or `00000000` and all that means that you want to omit it? You know that your design is a mess?

Comment: The data type is 'char' for these columns

Comment: I did not design the database. Just want to retrieve some data from it. I know it's a mess :-)

Comment: stop putting commas between tables in the from clause... use explicit join syntax only/always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE` and `NULLIF`(after replace of leading zeros with `''`)

```
SELECT 
    CashLimit = COALESCE(
       NULLIF(SUBSTRING(a.CashLimitAnnual,  PATINDEX('%[^0]%', a.CashLimitAnnual+'.'),  LEN(a.CashLimitAnnual)), ''),
       NULLIF(SUBSTRING(a.CashLimitQuarter, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', a.CashLimitQuarter+'.'), LEN(a.CashLimitQuarter)), ''),
       NULLIF(SUBSTRING(a.CashLimitMonth,   PATINDEX('%[^0]%', a.CashLimitMonth+'.'),   LEN(a.CashLimitMonth)), ''),
       NULLIF(SUBSTRING(a.CashLimitWeekly,  PATINDEX('%[^0]%', a.CashLimitWeekly+'.'),  LEN(a.CashLimitWeekly)), ''),
       NULLIF(SUBSTRING(a.CashLimitDaily,   PATINDEX('%[^0]%', a.CashLimitDaily+'.'),   LEN(a.CashLimitDaily)), ''),
    )
FROM   sqlcheck.dividend.dbo.testdata a, 
       dbo.testcompany b 
WHERE  a.companynumber = 1234 
       AND a.companynumber = b.conumber
```

`COALESCE` will take the first parameter which is not `NULL`. `NULLIF` will leave `NULLS` and treat other values as `NULL`, in this case empty strings. The `SUBSTRING` will remove all (leading)zeros from the column's to get an empty string if it is filled with zeros which then is treated as `NULL`.

Comment: This works perfectly. Awesome! Thanks, Tim Schmelter

Answer (score 0):

May Be you can try the COALESCE Function which will return the column without NULL values

So

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 1234, NULL, 789);
```

Result: 1234

But make sure that the value is null in all other fields or else you can use a replace to make it NULL during the select query like this

```
SELECT COALESCE(REPLACE(COL1,'000',NULL), NULL, 1234, NULL, 789);
```

Check this link for more information : [Coalesce](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/coalesce.php)

Comment: There is no null values for these columns. Either 0000000 or 00000000 or some amount like 00250000. Want to pick the column where amount not in(0000000 or 00000000)

Comment: use the replace like REPLACE(CashLimitAnnual,'00000000',NULL). Since your Database Design is wired, I think this is the only way. Or else you have to make the design changes to change Datatype to Numeric

Answer (score 0):

I propose you "unpivot" those columns, then present just the non-null value(s) with this approach you will know what the number represents, which a coalesce only based approach does not do.

The "unpivot" I suggest uses cross apply and values, not the unpivot feature, I find the approach below to be more direct and intuitive.

```
SELECT
      a.CompanyNumber
    , b.CoName
    , ca.type
    , SUBSTRING(ca.value,  PATINDEX('%[^0]%', ca.value+'.'),  LEN(ca.value))
FROM SQLcheck.dividend.dbo.testdata a
INNER JOIN dbo.testcompany b ON a.CompanyNumber = b.CoNumber
CROSS APPLY (
      VALUES
              ('CashLimitAnnual', CashLimitAnnual)
            , ('CashLimitQuarter', CashLimitQuarter)
            , ('CashLimitMonth', CashLimitMonth)
            , ('CashLimitWeekly', CashLimitWeekly)
            , ('CashLimitDaily', CashLimitDaily)
      ) ca (type, value)
INNER JOIN dbo.testcompany b ON a.CompanyNumber = b.CoNumber
WHERE a.CompanyNumber = 1234
AND ca.value IS NOT NULL
;
```

I have unabashedly borrowed from Tim Schmelter's approach to stripping the leading zeros, but that isn't the real focus of my suggestion.